# Getting data from a Google Sheet and using it to calculate costs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a calculator built that's working smoothly where users input a quantity and it calculates a price based on that input.

```
calculateQuantity(price) {

if (this.quantity <= 75) return 3.20;

if (this.quantity <= 100) return 2.72;

if (this.quantity <= 300) return 2.60;

if (this.quantity <= 500) return 2.58;

if (this.quantity >= 500) return 2.56;

}

calculate() {

subtotal = this.calculateQuantity(subtotal);

subtotal = subtotal * this.quantity;

this.subtotal = subtotal;
```

Now I need to link a Google sheet that will be updated daily to determine the prices in the above code but I'm at a loss. I've went through the Google API and I've gotten the sheet to display on a page but can't figure out how to grab a specific cell and use it a the price.

Essentially what I think I'm going for is something like

```
if (this.quantity <= 75) return (ROW 1:COLUMN 1);
```

If anyone can shed some light for me. I've scoured Google and most of what I'm finding is just how to basically display a sheet and not how to grab specific data and is it in the code.

Maybe there's a better solution where a non-techy client can easily input the prices to grab or even if Excel would be better.

Link to full code: https://jsfiddle.net/y893j5zm/

Comment: You can read the values from a Google Sheet using a GET request. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading for details.

Comment: About `I've went through the google api and I've gotten the sheet to display on a page but cant figure out how to grab a specific cell and use it a the price.`, can I ask you about the detail of this? And, although I saw your script, I cannot find the script related to this. I apologize for this. So, can you provide your tested script for using the Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Off topic: why is there a `price` parameter on the function, but is it never used?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions you need to do:

1. Create a Google sheet and put your "rating" from A1 to A5(3.20, 2.72, and so on...). Then, you can update it everday.
2. Create an Apps Script that links to the Google sheet. In the script, you need to create a function to do the following:

   - function with one input parameter(quantity).
   - based on the value of the quantity, return different "rating" (A1 to A5).

Reference link for creating an Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

3. Deploy an Apps Script as a webapp. Then, your page can use HTTP GET to invoke this API to calculate the "rating".

Reference link for creating Apps Script as a webapp: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web